# Is a woman allowed to massage her husband's prostate?

Tags: sex

Is it permissible for a woman to stimulate her husband's prostate (by using finger and her husband's anal opening)?

I am aware of this question [In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355) but it does not mentions prostate massage?

Comment: @ime do you mean as a sexual act or as remedy?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

I will answer your problem otherwise, you didn't tell us why you need to massage your prostate, but i guess that you have some [Erectile Dysfunction](http://yourbrainonporn.com/erectile-dysfunction-and-porn).
According to [Yourbrainonporn](http://yourbrainonporn.com) the problem is not in your organ rather is it in your brain.
I'm not sure about massaging prostate but it's not mentioned there, if you have an ED please read the [FAQ](http://yourbrainonporn.com/ask-us).

If you don't have any ED problems please consider this answer:

According to the book of Ibn al-Hajj named(`آداب قضاء الحاجة من كتاب المدخل لابن الحاج`):

(part of the book)

> **عدم إدخال الإصبع في الدبر(Do not enter the finger in the anus):**   الحذر من إدخال الإصبع في الدبر، قال:
>   فإنه من فعل شرار الناس، وهذه مسألة أيضاً من الأدب، ذكرها في قضية درجة
>   البطء في خروج الخارج، قال: فرب شخص يحصل له التنظيف عند انقطاع البول
>   عنه، فبمجرد أن ينقطع ولا يخرج شيء يغسل، وآخر لا يحصل له ذلك إلا بعد أن
>   يقوم ويقعد، يعني: ربما يحتاج شخص آخر إلى الاسترخاء ليخرج، وآخر يحتاج
>   أن يقوم ثم يقعد، إذا قام حضره بول إضافي غير الذي خرج منه فيقعد ليخرج
>   ما بقي، قال: وذلك راجع إلى اختلاف أحوال الناس في أمزجتهم ومآكلهم
>   واختلاف الأزمنة عليهم، فليس الشيخ كالشاب؛ لأنه معروف أن كبير السن
>   يسترخي معه المكان فتكثر عنده الحاجة لدخول دورة المياه عدة مرات، أما
>   الشاب فيكون الموضع عندهم مستمسك، وليس من أكل البطيخ كمن أكل الجبن؛ لأن
>   البطيخ يسبب شيئاً من الإسهال، والجبن يسبب شيئاً من الانقباض أو القبض،
>   وليس الحر كالبرد. المهم أنه ذكر اختلاف المآكل والأجواء، واختلاف أسنان
>   الناس، فهذه كلها أسباب في قضية التأخر أو البطء في الخارج، وبالتالي على
>   الإنسان أن ينتظر حتى يغسل كل شيء فيصلي وهو طاهر. وليس معنى هذا أن
>   الإنسان يقعد في دورة المياه ساعات، فإن بعض الناس عندهم وسوسة عجيبة،
>   كما ذكر ابن القيم رحمه الله حيث قال: وربما قفز درجات السلم، ينـزل على
>   سلم متتابعاً ثم يعود لأجل أن يفرغ ما في جعبته بظنه، وربما احتشى وآذى
>   نفسه، وأدخل أشياء في الداخل، وأنت لست مطالباً في الشريعة بتنظيف ما في
>   الداخل، بل أنت مطالب بتنظيف المخرج فقط، وأصلاً مهما نظفت في الداخل فإن
>   هذا موجود ومستودع داخل الإنسان، فالمطلوب هو تنظيف المخرج فقط، وليس ما
>   بالداخل، فأنت لست مسئولاً عما في الداخل. وبعض الناس يقول: انتظر ربما
>   يخرج شيء، وآفة الموسوسين كلمة: ربما، إني وجدت بالنظر في أحوال
>   الموسوسين أن آفتهم آفة عظيمة فيقول: ربما يمكن خرج شيء، يمكن يخرج شيء
>   بعد قليل، فهذه القضية الدقيقة عند الموسوسين، أنت مكلف بما صار الآن
>   ولست بمكلف بما يمكن أن يحدث، وتعمل لذلك احتياطات وتضيع الأوقات
>   والجماعات والصلاة، وصرح بعضهم أنه يضيع الصلاة عن وقتها كله من بعد
>   الظهر إلى العصر؛ وهذه من المصائب العظيمة، نسأل الله العافية؛ لأن قضية
>   الوسوسة مرض خطير جداً. فالإنسان مكلف بما يخرج، وليس بما يمكن..
>   احتمال.. شعرت.. إني أشعر. ثم أيضاً: لو أن الإنسان يخرج منه البول
>   متتابعاً ولا يستطيع التحكم في خروجه، فما هو الحكم؟ أنه يغسل ويتوضأ
>   ويخرج وليس بمكلف بما خرج منه بعد ذلك، يتوضأ بعد دخول الوقت ويصلي، وإن
>   وضع شيئاً كمناديل مثلاً أو شيئاً لئلا تنتشر النجاسة فقط. ولو كان يخرج
>   متتابعاً فإنه يخرج ولا يتحكم به إطلاقاً.

Which mean, is not permissible.

PS: Please improve my response by translating this part of the book, this could be helpful for the future readers.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is allowed for a woman to stimulate her husband's prostate (it usually happens before sex)

"the above answer in arabic is related to entering fingers in anus" that was not asked in question

Two of the things those are not allowed b/w the couple are:

1 . Oral sex ....

2 . To sex with women's back/anus

Comment: Oral sex is completely permissible, repsonse to is innacurate in that regard.

Comment: Please tell me what is the difference between prostate stimulation via the anus, and entering the fingers in the anus?

Comment: **nothing** . the answerer meant the same thing

Comment: Oral sex is not haram