# What is difference between sex from behind and anal sex in Islam?

Tags: sex

I learned that sex from behind in Islam is allowed, but not for anal sex, can you explain please and provide reference?

Comment: The answer can be found on http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-islam-are-there-limits-on-sex-between-a-married-couple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is doggie style sex allowed?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18749/is-doggie-style-sex-allowed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is this related question "[In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1355/11938)"

Simple difference, sex is allowed from any direction and even from behind(Can be rear position), but only **vaginal intercourse.**

But, sex is not allowed from any direction when it is anal intercourse.

May the creator guide us all.