# Is doggie style sex allowed?

Tags: fiqh, sex

Need to know what the ruling is on doggie style sex in the vagina? I know that anal sex is forbidden but I am asking about vaginal intercourse from behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jabir reported the Jews would say: "Whoever goes into his wife's vagina from behind her, then his children will be cross-eyed." So Allah revealed: **Your wives are a tilth for you, so go to your tilth when or how you will** (2:223).

[Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/16/138) and [Jami at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/639710)

The ayah itself is evidence that allows men to have sex with their wives from any way.