# Anal sex in a marriage

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sex

I am having issues. I am not arguing if it's allowed or not, it is just something that I need to clear up.

1. I keep reading that butt sex is haram because the word tilth is used
   in the Quran when saying go on to your wives the way you want to.
   But the same ayath is to justify oral sex, even though it doesn't
   get you pregnant. And does that mean contraception is not allowed?
2. They say it is not clean, but that's just a matter of opinion, and everyone showers daily, washes them selves, and keeps it clean.
   It is safe to assume that people are more hygienic now than ever
   before.
3. It is haram because it may harm her. With lube it doesn't hurt at all, and no medical reason for it to be harmful. It only hurts
   without proper warm up, and we are commanded to have foreplay so it
   shouldn't be an issue at all.
4. Also the hadeeth that forbid it, I read all over that they are weak, and shouldn't be taken into account because they contradict
   what the Quran says, go onto your wives how ever you want. (Allah
   swa is not shy to say the truth, don't have butt sex with your
   wives. And Allah swa will not look at him on the day of judgement
   who has butt sex with his wife.)

I don't want to withhold something from my marriage because of opinions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between sex from behind and anal sex in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/what-is-difference-between-sex-from-behind-and-anal-sex-in-islam)

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser the Questions here are much more and going deeper than your presented duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't take all those speculations to figure it out.

> And they ask you about menstruation. Say, "It is harm, so keep away from wives during menstruation. And do not approach them until they are pure. And when they have purified themselves, then come to them from where Allah has ordained for you. Indeed, Allah loves those who are constantly repentant and loves those who purify themselves." 2:222

The verse above shows how God uses menstruation subject to give a hint on from where a Believer should penetrate his wife.

Right after it is the verse you mentioned (and everyone is mentioning and basing their arguments)

> Your wives are a tilth for you, so go to your tilth , when or how you will, and send (good deeds, or ask Allah to bestow upon you pious offspring) before you for your ownselves. And fear Allah, and know that you are to meet Him (in the Hereafter), and give good tidings to the believers (O Muhammad SAW). 2:223

This verse leaves the freedom on how you would want your night with your wife to go (and there are so many things), and the previous verse only specifies from where to penetrate her and the condition to that. Making penetration[going inside] related to that specific area i.e the vagina and ruling out the other "potential" penetration area.

Comment: So back to what I said before...then contraception and oral sex fall into the same category as butt sex, if I'm not mistake this is only talking about vaginal sex. I am really sorry I know it's not the best topic to keep visiting. But I just need to know the justification of ruling out butt sex and not oral sex?

Comment: Because, fellatio, cunnilingus, and foreplays, whatever you guys are up to, seems to go into the second verse, of the freedom of sex (as seeking pleasure from one another). The first verse though does hint that the vagina is the area ordained by God for penetration, hence ruling out the anus for penetration. There was this question in here "is it ok to eat the booty" (lol) I'd categorise that as in the second verse too. If you get my logic.

Comment: @Noname I edited the last part of my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm not down to eat the booty but hey, I'm not one to say don't do something I'm not into. It's just weird. I didnt know about the butt sex until now. And I've been reading that verse thinking it meant all sex is good sex as long as it's with your wife. Now we have haram sex even in marriage. Honestly the verses are just saying make sure they are comfortable with what you are doing and be clean before getting dirty. Its not pointing at anything other than that. But honestly don't you penetrate the mouth during oral sex?

Comment: It's ok buddy, I'm not here to tell you what you should or shouldn't do either, the judgement is to God. And the Quran calls for the right path, thus why we should ponder and reflect in it.

Comment: I just read the edit to your comment, "don't you penetrate the mouth during oral sex" if I thought that it's a penetration as refered to the first verse, then I won't do it. If you think otherwise then do it, but we all agree that anal sex is about penetration so it's clear for that case.

Comment: Wait...you can eat the booty but no butt sex? Come on man what happened to consistency? The thing about the ulima is that I read even oral sex is haram and even looking at your wife naked is wrong. That's kind of why I posted the question. For a definitive answer. Not opinions and "hints" towards things because everything is halal unless ruled otherwise.

Comment: Ok that last post from you... clarifying penitration...that's what I was in need of. Thanks You

Comment: Read the edit I made to the answer, not the comments please

Comment: Your answer is mostly based on assumptions @user19208 . OP makes a good point with "Allah swa is not shy to say the truth". Why here?

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented this topic and my God showed me that anal sex was not permissible because it disconnect the conscious from the Self Divine, in arabicالروح المقدسة, the ungodly act is dangerous karmically, it may materialise in djinns or vicious people in one's life, there is more to say about it but i don't know the subject and is not interested in the subject. You should meditate on something that clear out the path instead of having too much cravings. Even fingers in ass is not permissible

Answer (score -1):

Penetrating the penis in anus or mouth both are haram as shown by the first verse of reference given above. it is very clear that if you want to penetrate then after menstruation period, you can have sex in vagina only. this does not allow oral or anus sex at that time, why? because that are haram. foreplay does not mean to suck genitals. it means to kiss on every body part but not on genitals as clear in the first verse that penis should be penetrated only into the vagina when free from menses. if you can penetrate in anus or mouth then why there is prohibition for menses. because genitals are specified for us to use according and foreplay does not include any kind of dick sucking or ass fucking at all. its the satan, the devil who want to mislead us in this regard. and people of lot a prophet were destroyed due to this ass penetration. and there is no difference that whether its a male or female anus, its against the will of God. in the second ayat, if you see the tafseer, then it is clear that its about the sex position i.e. doggy style etc and not about the anus. moreover kheti or farm is cultivated with seed. and our sperm is a seed and the right place of seed is vagina which results in kids. so the true application of kheti or farm is achieved when you penetrated only in vagina.