# Is it halal to eat the booty?

Tags: sharia

Hi I'm not really knowledgeable about my religion so I need to know more. There's this huge trend going on in the world about licking your girl's ass better said (eating the booty=ass).

I wanna know if its halal because I'm not really penetrating it with my penis?

Comment: Please see http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-islam-are-there-limits-on-sex-between-a-married-couple. You're obviously trolling but nevertheless,  you should be forwarded to an answer instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the Quran and hadith that prohibits what you have asked about. However, it is essential to check if the region is clean or not as khabaith is strictly haram [[7:157](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.yusufali/7:157)].

Among the scholars, there is a difference of opinion<sup>[source](http://islamhelpline.net/node/3568)</sup>. One group completely [forbids it](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90583) to avoid sin, other group expresses [permissibility](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/20244), some with [reluctance](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/9310).

Hence you do anything as long as it is not anal penetration.

---

To resonate with your words, it is *not haraam* to eat the booty, but not the shit.

<sub>**not haraam means either halal or makruh**</sub>